# Is WebClient (still) unreliable in Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, webclient

I have some code that uses the WebClient class that runs in the WP Emulator, and a WP device. I have succesfully run the same code on the iPhone Simulator using Monotouch. But on the iPhone itself the App crashes.

According to this link it could be due to the encoding http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/533484-webclient-encoding-issue-in-monotouch-when-building-for-release

So I hope that will solve my immediate problem.

But this leads to my question. During my research I found this article from 2010 http://escoz.com/blog/webclient-reliability-problems-under-monotouch/ According to this there is a general problem with reliability of WebClient on Monotouch and it should be avoided. Is this true ? And if so has it been solved ?

Comment: without the crash log it is hard to guess whether it is the same or a different problem.

Comment: It turns out my problem had to do with the Json deserializer. I tried ServiceStack.Text.Monotouch.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll though both where the newest version compiled for Monotouch they only work on the Emulator. On the device they do not work, since they both use some level of reflection to automatize the deserialization - I do not know if there is something to do about this. It is weird that both products claim to work on monotouch when the don't - so the fault might be mine. In stead I had to use manual json deserialization with the System.Json namespace.